# Python: using int() on a string that is not an integer literal

Tags: python, string, numpy

Note: I was using the wrong source file for my data - once that was fixed, my issue was resolved. It turns out, there is no simple way to use `int(..)` on a string that is not an integer literal.

This is an example from the book "Machine Learning In Action", and I cannot quite figure out what is wrong. Here's some background:

```
from numpy import as *

def file2matrix(filename):
    fr = open(filename)
    numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())
    returnMat = zeros((numberOfLines,3))
    classLabelVector = []
    fr = open(filename)
    index = 0
    for line in fr.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        listFromLine = line.split('\t')
        returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
        classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1])) # Problem here.
        index += 1
    return returnMat,classLabelVector
```

The .txt file is as follows:

```
40920   8.326976    0.953952    largeDoses
14488   7.153469    1.673904    smallDoses
26052   1.441871    0.805124    didntLike
75136   13.147394   0.428964    didntLike
38344   1.669788    0.134296    didntLike
...
```

I am getting an error on the line `classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))` because, I believe, `int(..)` is trying to parse over a String (ie `"largeDoses"`) that is a not a literal integer. Am I missing something?

I looked up the documentation for `int()`, but it only seems to parse numbers and integer literals:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Also, an excerpt from the book explains this section as follows:

> Finally, you loop over all the lines in the file and strip off the return line character with line.strip(). Next, you split the line
>   into a list of elements delimited by the tab character: '\t'. You take
>   the first three elements and shove them into a row of your matrix, and
>   you use the Python feature of negative indexing to get the last item
>   from the list to put into classLabelVector. You have to explicitly
>   tell the interpreter that you’d like the integer version of the last
>   item in the list, or it will give you the string version. Usually,
>   you’d have to do this, but NumPy takes care of those details for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strings like "largeDoses" could not be converted to integers. In folder `Ch02` of [that code project](https://github.com/pbharrin/machinelearninginaction), you have two data files, use the second one `datingTestSet2.txt` instead of loading the first

Comment: Wow, thanks - I did not see the other file. I may just close this question since it seems trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and catch the exception ValueError the malformed string (by the way int('9.4') will raise an exception)